# Exponential and Hyperbolic Functions Before Power Series

Tags: reference-request, exponential-function, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-functions

Is there a textbook that covers the exponential function and the possibly the hyperbolic functions from a precalculus geometrical viewpoint?  I'm essentially asking for something like a trigonometry book but for real exponentials and hyperbolic functions instead of trigonometric functions.  Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at the first two or three chapters in [**Hyperbolic Functions: with Configuration Theorems and Equivalent and Equidecomposable Figures**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486458865), which is an English translation of essays originally published in Russian.